# jQuery AJAX - send file and variable to PHP in single request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following HTML form for uploading a file (picture):

```
<input id="sortpicture" type="file" name="sortpic" />
<button id="upload">Upload</button>
```

I use the following JavaScript/jQuery to send form data and a variable value to PHP script:

```
var variable1= 1;

$('#upload').on('click', function() {
    var file_data = $('#sortpicture').prop('files')[0];   
    var form_data = new FormData();                  
    form_data.append('file', file_data);

    $.ajax({
                url: 'upload.php', // point to server-side PHP script 
                dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: {form_data, number: variable1},                         
                type: 'post',
                success: function(php_script_response){
                alert(php_script_response); // display response from the PHP script, if any
            }
    });
});
```

The PHP script (upload.php) looks like this:

```
$filename;
if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
}
else {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
}
echo $filename;
```

When I run this code, PHP throws some undefined index errors. If I use only "data: form_data" in ajax request (without variable1), then the file uploads successfully, but I need to send the variable too. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also append the `number` key => value to to the form data as

```
form_data.append('number',  variable1);
```

Then in Ajax call

```
data: form_data,
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you append this value like this

```
form_data.append('number', variable1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Append the variable to form_data

```
var form_data = new FormData();                  
form_data.append('file', file_data);
form_data.append('number', variable1); // append variable
```

In ajax

```
processData: false,
data: form_data,    // data                   
type: 'post',
```

Answer (score 0):

I am following your code because I need FILES image data and multiple variables in PHP script for insertion operation in the database. But I am unable to access any single variable in the php script. I did below to access your number variable. Please correct me.

```
//upload.php
        if(isset($_GET['number'])){
             $num = $_GET['number'];
             echo $num;
    
        }else{
            echo 'not set';
        }
```

Comment: Kindly help me. I am unable to access this variable in PHP script

Comment: Try using $_POST instead of $_GET. I'm using POST request in example above.